# How should I extend a case class if a derived class is meant to have the same parameter and shouldn't override?

Tags: scala, inheritance, case-class

```
case class Message(xml : Node) {
  def toXML : Node = xml
}

case class ReqValidationMessage (xml : Node) extends Message(xml){
  // ...
}
```

This causes a property naming conflict as Scala tries to create a second property named xml in ReqValidationMessage case class. But I want both constructors (of Message and ReqValidationMessage) to have the same argumentation. What should I do?

Comment: Why do you need a case class for both child and parent ? What features are needed ?

Comment: Because depending on the reason, different solutions may exists.

Comment: I like the idea of having all the case class implicit goodness for both of them. I supposed the solution is very simple and beautyful but yet unknown to me because of lack of experience (as always in Scala :-) ) Some ideas come into my mind, but all seem just clumsy.

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is: You should not extend a case class — case class inheritance is now deprecated.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of subclassing case classes, why not use mixins to replicate common features:

```
trait XMLConvertible {
  def xml: Node
  def toXML = xml
}

case class Message(xml : Node) extends XMLConvertible

case class ReqValidationMessage(xml : Node) extends XMLConvertible {
  //...
}
```

Then if you want to use directly `XMLConvertible` for pattern matching add a companion object:

```
object XMLConvertible {
   def unapply( xc: XMLConvertible ) = Some( xc.xml )
}
```

Which allows you to write:

```
case XMLConvertible(xml) => println( xml )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with the scheme you presented, then you can just change the name of argument in second constructor - to something like xml2. Then you will have no naming conflict, and everything will work.